# How to see macro expansions step-by-step?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, c-preprocessor, compiler-options

It seems [Eclipse allows user to "see the expansion Step-by-Step" by pressing F2.](http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/reading-code/macro-expansions/)

I like this awesome feature. But can I do the same thing with just `gcc` or `clang` (or any tool)?

`-E` option makes all macros fully expanded. So I haven't found any alternative way to expand macros step-by-step.

Eclipse is big. I hope I don't need to install it everywhere and have it launched all the time.

Comment: `-E` option is for gcc  . I don't quite understand what alternative you want .

Comment: @ameyCU I want a lightweight way to see the step-by-step expansion, like the feature in Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature built into Eclipse. If such a tool was provided as part of the GCC or Clang toolchain, Eclipse would have no need to implement it. Such a feature could be implemented as an extension to GCC using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/). LLVM (of which Clang is a part of) is designed to make something like this trivial.

One thing you have to keep in mind that macro expansion is a tricky business. At any given point in time, a macro definition may change or not exist at all. Theoretically you could use `gdb` (the debugger that comes with GCC) to step through your program to see macro expansions at different point in the program. If you want, you could try writing a `gdb` plugin in Python.

Comment: maros are fully expanded at(or before, by preprocessor) compile time, how can gdb see expansion steps at runtime.